# React-Navigation goBack() 2 screen and update the parent state

Tags: react-native

I've a screen route as below

1. Tab ( Tab Navigator ) , it has screen of "Home" and "Mine"
2. Stack ( StackNavigator ), it has screen of "Settings" and "UpdateProfile"

as below

```
const Tab = TabNavigator(
{
        Home: { screen: HomeScene },
        Mine: { screen: Mine }
});

const Navigator = StackNavigator(
{
    Tab: { screen: Tab },
    Settings : { screen: SettingsScene },
    UpdateProfile : { screen: UpdateProfile },
});
```

In "Mine" screen, it will show user name and there is an option to navigate to "Settings" screen.

In "Settings" screen, i can navigate to "UpdateProfile" and update my profile details.

What i want to do is, when i update the profile name in "UpdateProfile", the user name is "Mine" screen is not updated.

Is there a way to navigate directly to Tab -> Mine screen and update the user name from "UpdateProfile" screen?

PS: i'm not using Redux and Flux.

Comment: Check this post
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223727/react-navigation-goback-and-update-parent-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223727/react-navigation-goback-and-update-parent-state)