# React navigation goBack() and update parent state

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've a page that will render the user's name if s/he is logged in or "Create an account" or "Sign in" option if s/he not. Screen as below

[image]

They can navigate to "Sign in" or "Create an account" page. After successfully signing in or registering, it will navigate to this page and it will show the user name. Screen as below

[image]

Currently, I store user data in `AsyncStorage`, I want to update this field once the user successfully logs in or register when they redirect from the page.

How can I achieve this?

is there a way to pass param from `navigate.goBack()` and parent can listen to the params and update its state?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can pass a callback function as parameter when you call navigate like this:

```js
  const DEMO_TOKEN = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token');
  if (DEMO_TOKEN === null) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {
      onGoBack: () => this.refresh(),
    });
    return -3;
  } else {
    this.doSomething();
  }
```

And define your callback function:

```js
refresh() {
  this.doSomething();
}
```

Then in the login/registration view, before goBack, you can do this:

```js
await AsyncStorage.setItem('id_token', myId);
this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack();
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

**Update for React Navigation v5:**

```js
await AsyncStorage.setItem('id_token', myId);
this.props.route.params.onGoBack();
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

Comment: Hi, if I use `static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({ headerRight: <Button title="test" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('GoToScreen', {onGoBack: () => this.refresh()})} /> });` it gets annoyed that there is no `this.refresh()`. Any solutions?

Comment: Even if i don't use `this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack();`, it is still calling `refresh()`

Comment: I can't find the reference now, but I saw a warning from a react-navigation developer that callback functions in params aren't guaranteed to work, because the params can be serialized into a file and then reinstated, at which point your callbacks will be lost.

Comment: You can also use `onGoBack: this.refresh`  instead of `onGoBack: () => this.refresh()`

Comment: This pretty much requires a gist or a little bit more defining of what is actually happening in explicit code, because the concept communicated is large and also important.

Comment: Still not solve my issue :( im using react navigation 2.0

Comment: For React Navigation 5.0, use this.props.route.params.onGoBack()

Comment: In v5, you will get "We found non-serializable values in the navigation state, which can break usage such as persisting and restoring state if you just pass a callback function.

Comment: Any ideas how to solve the warning "We found non-serializable values in the navigation state, which can break usage such as persisting and restoring state if you just pass a callback function" in v5?

Comment: One option is to use navigation events in the parent. The event will fire each time the view is navigated to. This isn't quite the same but in some cases it's close enough. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/

Comment: The official option is to ".navigate" back to the view instead of ".goBack", and pass in a parameter. Since the route name is the same, it will pop the current route off instead of adding a new one. If the parent is a function component you can do ```useEffect(refresh, [route.params?.updateTime])``` and in the child do ```.navigate("parent", {updateTime: new Date().getTime()})```.

Comment: Use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64257347/5501242

Comment: Navigation events used to return which screen you came from, which was useful. On v5 they don't anymore, so you're stuck with sending the target screen where you're coming from, and `navigate`ing from there instead of `goBack()`ing

Comment: But if I write an common page that do something with a callback, so I don't know `parent page`'s name. What can do in this situation?

Comment: @mrvladimir, the official option is completely useless peace of advice.

I am writing a common hook, that redirects to the page which receives some data and should redirect back with this data.

(!) It is used on multiple pages and and stacks.

Since `react-native-router` does not allow me to get name of a current stack, how am I supposed to redirect user back to it?

Answer (score 73):

> is there a way to pass param from `navigate.goback()` and parent can listen to the params and update its state?

You can pass a callback function as parameter (as mentioned in other answers).

Here is a more **clear example**, when you navigate from A to B and you want B to communicate information back to A you can pass a callback (here `onSelect`):

**`ViewA.js`**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

class ViewA extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: false };

  onSelect = data => {
    this.setState(data);
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigate("ViewB", { onSelect: this.onSelect });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.selected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected"}</Text>
        <Button title="Next" onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**`ViewB.js`**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class ViewB extends React.Component {
  goBack() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
    navigation.state.params.onSelect({ selected: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <Button title="back" onPress={this.goBack} />;
  }
}
```

Hats off for [debrice](https://github.com/debrice) - Refer to https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/288#issuecomment-315684617

---

### Edit

> For React Navigation v5

**`ViewB.js`**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class ViewB extends React.Component {
  goBack() {
    const { navigation, route } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
    route.params.onSelect({ selected: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <Button title="back" onPress={this.goBack} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful for a case I had today when I needed to keep track of unsaved items on a page. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Hey! I might be late, but Im getting an error called ```undefined is not an object (evaluating navigation.state.params.onSelect)``` is not a function,

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution from Debrice. It works perfectly as expected (:

Comment: @MinUD please use `this.props.route.params.onSelect`

Comment: I had to add `bind(this)` in order `this.setState()` be able to work. So
`onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigate("ViewB", { onSelect: this.onSelect.bind(this) });
  };`

Comment: @FosAvance did you try this? `{ onSelect: () => this.onSelect() }`

Comment: @gihanchanuka it's not working, nothing is passed back then

Comment: P.S. because if `bind(this)` I get:  "Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check:

Contacts > params.returnData (Function)

This can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. "

Answer (score 23):

For those who don't want to manage via props, try this. It will call everytime when this page appear.

> Note* (this is not only for goBack but it will call every-time you
>   enter this page.)

```js
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <NavigationEvents
              onWillFocus={() => {
                // Do your things here
              }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: weird, but best solution ever. it helps when we wants to refresh anytime.

Comment: This is the best answer, simple and very effective, I needed to refresh a screen every time I went back to it, with either a navigation or a back press, and this solves it with no complications.

Answer (score 20):

I was facing a similar issue, so here is how I solved it by going more into details.

**Option one** is to navigate back to parent with parameters, just define a callback function in it like this *in parent component*:

```js
updateData = data => {
  console.log(data);
  alert("come back status: " + data);
  // some other stuff
};
```

and navigate to the child:

```js
onPress = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("ParentScreen", {
    name: "from parent",
    updateData: this.updateData
  });
};
```

*Now in the child it can be called:*

```js
 this.props.navigation.state.params.updateData(status);
 this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

---

**Option two.** In order to get data from any component, as the other answer explained, AsyncStorage can be used either synchronously or not.

Once data is saved it can be used anywhere.

```js
// to get
AsyncStorage.getItem("@item")
  .then(item => {
    item = JSON.parse(item);
    this.setState({ mystate: item });
  })
  .done();
// to set
AsyncStorage.setItem("@item", JSON.stringify(someData));
```

or either use an async function to make it self-update when it gets new value doing like so.

```js
this.state = { item: this.dataUpdate() };
async function dataUpdate() {
  try {
    let item = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@item");
    return item;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

See the [AsyncStorage docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) for more details.

Comment: First approach worked for me. My objective was to refersh some data when child is poped.

Comment: @David In my case i gave headerMode as screen.So that the back button at left is automatically provided.I dont want to change the icon.But i want to do some function after goBack() to previous screen.Please tell me how to do this?

Comment: see also this example with the same approach as Option 1 https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1416#issuecomment-300489310

Comment: Option 1 like closure in swift. it's work exactly, thanks bro

Comment: I got a warning Message dude " [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.state.params')] "

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is using [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html). You don't need to create listeners manually.

Calling a callback function is not highly recommended. Check this example using a listener (Remember to remove all listeners from componentWillUnMount with this option).

Component A:

```js
navigateToComponentB() {
  const { navigation } = this.props
  this.navigationListener = navigation.addListener('willFocus', payload => {
    this.removeNavigationListener()
    const { state } = payload
    const { params } = state
    //update state with the new params
    const { otherParam } = params
    this.setState({ otherParam })
  })
  navigation.push('ComponentB', {
    returnToRoute: navigation.state,
    otherParam: this.state.otherParam
  })
}
removeNavigationListener() {
  if (this.navigationListener) {
    this.navigationListener.remove()
    this.navigationListener = null
  }
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.removeNavigationListener()
}
```

Commponent B:

```js
returnToComponentA() {
  const { navigation } = this.props
  const { routeName, key } = navigation.getParam('returnToRoute')
  navigation.navigate({ routeName, key, params: { otherParam: 123 } })
}
```

For more details of the previous example: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/288#issuecomment-378412411

Comment: Worked wonderfully - agree this is the nicest solution IMO from what I've encountered so far

Answer (score 11):

With React Navigation v5, just use the navigate method. From the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen):

> To achieve this, you can use the navigate method, which acts like
> goBack if the screen already exists. You can pass the params with
> navigate to pass the data back

Full example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function ScreenA ({ navigation, route }) {
  const { params } = route;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Params: {JSON.stringify(params)}</Text>
      <Button title='Go to B' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('B')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function ScreenB ({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title='Go to A'
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('A', { data: 'Something' })
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
        <Stack.Screen name="A" component={ScreenA} />
        <Stack.Screen name="B" component={ScreenB} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: This is the correct (up-to-date) answer - wonder why it is so far down.

Comment: this messes up the stack history. goBack removes the the current screen from the history stack while `navigation.navigate` just pushes new screen on the stack.

Comment: So, I initially downvoted this because of the same reason as @Dawit but it turns out if you read the doc that is what they recommend to do in v6 still, I have no idea why they would implement it like that, it is very unconventional ... but we got a winner here!

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way to **render the required components** is by using **useIsFocused** hook.

React Navigation provides a hook that returns a boolean indicating whether the screen is focused or not. The hook will return true when the screen is focused and false when our component is no longer focused.

First import this in the required page where you want to navigate back.
`import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';`

Then, store this in any variable, and render components changes using React useEffect hook.

See code below or visit: [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#re-rendering-screen-with-the-useisfocused-hook)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/core';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  
  useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("Focused: ", isFocused); //called whenever isFocused changes
    }, [isFocused]);
    
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> This is home screen! </Text>
      </View>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution did it for me, according to the navigation site: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#re-rendering-screen-with-the-useisfocused-hook

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => { 
        // YOUR CODE WHEN IT IS FOCUSED
       return // YOUR CODE WHEN IT'S UNFOCUSED
    }, [userId])
);
```

Comment: While some of the other solutions could also work, for me this was the best solution 'cause it meant that I didn't need to muddy the state going between components just to get a component to re-render when the screen gains focus again.

Answer (score 3):

I just used standard navigate function giving ViewA route name and passing the parameters, did exactly what goBack would have done.

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate("ViewA", 
{
     param1: value1, 
     param2: value2
});
```

Comment: This is **NOT** the same as `goBack()`. This goes forwards to the previous view (it's adding to the stack). And furthermore, I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: I think it does - the question is "how to go back with params". That is regardless of your comment on going back vs going forward . In either case the params can be passed and received by the "back" screen.

Comment: But... you’re not “going back” with this method. You’re only going forwards to the previous page, and passing the same props as was originally used on it (plus any new ones). This can be visualised with the transitions used. For example, going forwards might slide a new page in from the right (with a shadow so it appears above the current page) and have it finish on the left, while going back might slide the current page from the left to the right, leaving the previous page “underneath” (appearing so with the use of shadow).

Comment: @ElliotSchep If the route is already on the stack, calling `this.props.navigation.navigate` *is* the same as calling `goBack()`. Test it out, you'll see. The screen animation slides from left to right.

Comment: @Bataleon I wasn't aware of this. Sorry morgan_il

Comment: @ElliotSchep No problem, it's a bit confusing and not what I would call "expected" behavior. I also assumed `navigation.navigate` always resulted in a route being pushed onto the stack.

Comment: navigation.navigate will go back to that route if its in the stack. If you want to push new navigation to the stack use navigation.push

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `redux` you can create an action to store data and check the value in parent `Component` or you can use `AsyncStorage`.

But I think it's better to passing only `JSON-serializable` params, because if someday you want to save state of navigation, its not very easy.

Also note `react-navigation` has this feature in experimental
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/state-persistence.html

> Each param, route, and navigation state must be fully
> JSON-serializable for this feature to work. This means that your
> routes and params must contain no functions, class instances, or
> recursive data structures.

I like this feature in **Development Mode** and when I pass params as function I simply can't use it

Comment: redus? I think you mean 'redux'

Comment: @ScottJodoin ops, typo

Answer (score 1):

Passing a callback through React Navigation in v5 throws a warning:

`This can break usage such as persisting and restoring state`

You can execute some code in screen A when you navigate back to it from Screen B in two easy ways:

First:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const willFocusSubscription = navigation.addListener("focus", () => handleRefresh());
    return () => willFocusSubscription
}, []);
```

This gets the job done. However, this method will be executed every time the screen is rendered.
In order to only render it once when navigating back you can do the following:

Screen A:

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from "react-native";

useEffect(() => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("userIsGoingBack", () => handleRefresh());
    return () => DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners("listingCreated");            
}, []);
```

Screen B:

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from "react-native";

DeviceEventEmitter.emit("userIsGoingBack");
```

You can also pass some data alongside the emitted event to use in screen A if needed.

Answer (score 1):

use Merge
[take a look (react navigation 6.x)[1](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

in the latest version of react navigation (v6.x), you can use `navigate` as normal instead of `goBack` if you want to pass params while going back (as navigate keeps the stack).

```
navigation.navigate('screenname', {param: value});
```

if the `screenname` screen is in the stack and is the previos screen as compared to the current screen, then navigate will act as goBack.

More details [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen)

Answer (score 1):

```
navigation.dispatch(state => {
    const prevRoute = state.routes[state.routes.length - 2];
    return CommonActions.navigate({
      name: prevRoute.name,
      params: {},
      merge: true,
    });
  });
```

Comment: This is for 6.x react navigation, this way there is no need to pass previusScreen param

Answer (score 0):

I would also use navigation.navigate. If someone has the same problem and also uses **nested navigators**, this is how it would work:

```
onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('MyStackScreen', {
          // Passing params to NESTED navigator screen:
          screen: 'goToScreenA',
          params: { Data: data.item },
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any answer to work for my specific use case. I have a list being fetched from a database and a screen to add another list item. I wanted that once a user creates the item on the second screen, the app should navigate back to the first screen and show the newly added item in the list. Although the item was being added in the database, the list was not updating  to reflect the change. The solution that worked for me: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation.github.io/issues/191#issuecomment-641018588

So all I did was put this on the first screen and now the useEffect is triggered every time the screen is in focus or loses focus.
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
useEffect(() => {
    // Code to run everytime the screen is in focus
}, [isFocused]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `react-navigation` version 6 I implemented it by passing a parameter while navigating to another page then calling that parameter which is function beside `goBack()` function like this

Screen A :

```
navigation.navigate("Screen B", { refresh: () => getData() })
```

Screen B :

```
const { refresh } = route.params;

navigation.goBack();
refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to tackle this issue, `react-navigation` provides a neat solution, especially from version 6 onwards.

check this example:

1. **In `ScreenA` (from where you navigate to `ScreenB`)**:
   When you navigate to `ScreenB`, you don't need to pass anything special.

   ```js
   navigation.navigate('ScreenB');
   ```
2. **In `ScreenB` (where you collect/generate the data to pass back)**:
   After obtaining the necessary data, you can pass it back to `ScreenA` using:

   ```js
   const someData = "Your Data"; // This can be any data you wish to pass back
   navigation.navigate('ScreenA', { dataFromB: someData });
   ```
3. **Back in `ScreenA`**:
   Listen for the data passed from `ScreenB`:

   ```js
   useEffect(() => {
     if (route.params?.dataFromB) {
       // Use the data here as required
       console.log(route.params.dataFromB);
     }
   }, [route.params?.dataFromB]);
   ```

As highlighted in the `react-navigation` docs:

> Params can transfer data not only to a new screen but also back to a previous one. If a screen is already in the stack, the `navigate` method acts like `goBack` with the added ability to pass parameters.

For other ways to share data:

1. **Callback Functions**: Use `navigation.setParams()` to pass a callback function, then call it in `ScreenB` to send data back.
2. **useContext**: Leverage React's `useContext` for shared data between screens.
3. **State Managers**: Employ state management tools like Redux, MobX, or Zustand.

All these methods are valid, but I think it depends mainly on the needs of each one, but definitely the least complex and easiest to maintain is using `navigate.navigate()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * 返回上一页携带参数, 不需要传递 screen name
 *
 * react-native-navigation 6.x
 * https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/76581949/4348530
 * @param params
 */
export const goBack = params => {
  const navigation = navigationRef.current;
  if (navigation?.isReady()) {
    if (!params) {
      navigation.goBack();
    } else {
      navigation.dispatch(state => {
        if (state.routes.length >= 2) {
          const prevRoute = state.routes[state.routes.length - 2];
          return CommonActions.navigate({
            name: prevRoute.name,
            params: params,
            merge: true,
          });
        } else {
          return CommonActions.goBack();
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also spent a long time looking for a practical solution for this. In the end, it was Michael Mao's solution. I just modified it a little, as I often work with the useNavigation() hook (tested with react-navigation 6.x) :

```
export const goBackWithParams = (navigation, params) => {

    if (!params) {
        navigation.goBack();
        return;
    }

    navigation.dispatch(state => {
        if (state.routes.length >= 2) {
            const prevRoute = state.routes[state.routes.length - 2];

            return CommonActions.navigate({
                name: prevRoute.name,
                params: params,
                merge: true,
            });

        } else {
            return CommonActions.goBack();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

First screen

```js
updateData=(data)=>{
    console.log('Selected data',data)
}   

this.props.navigation.navigate('FirstScreen',{updateData:this.updateData.bind(this)})
```

Second screen

```js
// use this method to call FirstScreen method 
execBack(param) {
    this.props.navigation.state.params.updateData(param);
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```