# Route not updating state from navigation params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have this screen that show product details, it works like a template because only the data coming navigation params changes, I am having the issue because there's no reload, it works fine when going back and mounting it again, that's not the case here since I have related products showing on that same screen, I'll need a way to be able to either reload the current route or update the state

I have checked with console.log nothing shows up on second click

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    product: this.props.route.params.product,
    id: this.props.route.params.product.id,
  }
}
```

To navigate to use to the route I use on both the screen itself or in another route

```
viewProduct = (product) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('SingleProduct', { product: product })
}
```

I have tried setState inside of both `componentDidMount` and `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` but the results only shows after an additional click

Comment: Can you please let me know version of react-navigation and react-native ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh previous screen on goBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504660/refresh-previous-screen-on-goback)

Comment: Here is the link of answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65869570/13789135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function to navigate from singleProduction screen to the same screen with the different params.

```
this.props.navigation.replace('SingleProduct', { product: product })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
navigation.setParams({
   query: 'someText',
});
```

Taken from [react navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#updating-params)

Answer (score 0):

use the `route.params?.product` directly and mention change in `useEffect` array.

```
  useEffect(() => {

    return () => {
      // Clean up the subscription
      
    };
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [route.params?.product]);
```