# Why my screen is not refreshed when I go back from previous Stack.screen?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, graphql

I use `react-native` with `graphQL`.

I have **Screen2**: EditPhoto.

here, I change caption through `mutation` of graphQL.

And then if I press button, it will go back to **Screen1** which is Photo through `navigate.goBack()`.

> (Screen2 -> Screen1)

```
  const EditValid = () => {
    editPhotoMutation();
    navigation.goBack();
  };

    <SmallButton
      styleB={{ backgroundColor: `${colors.normal}` }}
      styleBT={{ color: `${colors.lightgray}`, fontSize: 20 }}
      text={"확인"}
      onPress={handleSubmit(EditValid)}
    />
```

When I go back to Screen1, I want this changed caption to be applied.

But it's not, and I know that screen is only rendered `once`, it's not possible.

So I searched the way to refresh Screen1.

[Refresh previous screen on goBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504660/refresh-previous-screen-on-goback)

According to this suggestion, I tried to use `useEffect` and `navigation.addListener`.

```
  const { data, loading, refetch, fetchMore } = useQuery(FEED_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      offset: 0,
    },
  });
  const [feedData, setFeedData] = useState(data?.seeFeed);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      refetch();
      setFeedData(data?.seeFeed);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

what I want is simple.

I want to `refetch()` Feed query again and want to put `feedData` with refetched data.

But it doens't work.
when I go back to Screen1, data remains same.

Please help me~~ :(

---

when I `console.log` data, it seems when I go back to Screen1, UI is rendered again.

But `refetching way` is strange..?

Because when I console.log the data, if I go back from Screen1, data is console.log-ed once again.
but just data is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use useIsFocused() hook for this.

```
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    yourFunction();
  },[isFocused]);
```

EDIT ==>
The other way and solution which worked for this particular situation:-

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(true);  
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      if(active){
        refresh();
        setActive(false)
      }
    },[data?.seeFeed?.length])
  );
```

Also had to pass data?.seeFeed directly to data prop in flatList

Comment: thanks. but it doesn't work. guess you code is right but `refetch()` seems not right? can you review it also? otherwise, I also learned `redux` but since i'm a beginner, don't know how to implement this case in redux, can you just tell me brief picture to me?

Comment: I guess useEffect is run after rendering UI. but in order to refresh UI, I need to run this function in useEffect `before` UI is rendered.

Comment: yes useEffect is called just after first render, if you want to call something before that you'll need useLayoutEffect. I am not familiar with React query so not sure what's refetch function is doing.

Comment: Also you can try the example provided by Hardik desai. Just call your refetch function inside the useCallback and pass feedData as a dependancy array.

Comment: `  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      refetch();
      setFeedData(data?.seeFeed);
    }, [])
  );` I did this code but doesn't work T_T

Comment: useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      refetch();
      const set = setFeedData(data?.seeFeed);
      return () => ?;
    })
  );

Comment: I made above code and it successfully applied but screen is strange keep rolling up and down flatlist.  what should i return in `?` part?

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly does refetch do?

Comment: refetch is literally rerun query. so it re-call the data from server again. so if my back data changes, then I recall (=refetch) it to apply the change

Comment: This solution worked for me when I would change data in storage using AsyncStorage on one screen and needed the data to render on another. Hopefully this can help someone:

Main screen code: 
`  useEffect(() => {
   const setData = async () => {
    const ret = await AsyncStorage.getItem("foo")
    setlocalfoo(ret)
   }
   setData()
  }, [isFocused])`   

other screen code: 

`
const handlePress = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('foo', streakTitle + " value")
 } `

Answer (score 3):

This can be achived by `useFocusEffect` from `'@react-navigation/native'`

useFocusEffect will effect every time when screen is focus

Ref: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Profile({ }) {
 

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      
// Below alert will fire every time when this screen is focused
   alert('Hi')
      
    }, [])
  );

  return // ...code
}
```

Comment: I'm a new to React native, can you show me some code how to apply this with my above code?

Comment: is this `API.subscribe` kind `redux`?

Comment: Please have a look into this basic example https://snack.expo.dev/8bz2pwsYX