# How to reset the first screen in a navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my react native app I am navigating from one navigator to a screen in another navigator like this

```
navigation.navigate(Screens.EXPLORE, {
                  screen: Screens.BRIEF,
                  params: {
                    briefId: briefInfo.campaign_id,
                  },
                });
```

However once I do this and tap the back button and which returns me the the screen before in its own navigator, if I try to navigate to the other navigator by clicking the icon which should navigate to the home screen of that navigator, it navigates still to the screen I navigated before, within the navigator. Is it possible in any way that when I click the back button in the screen to reset the navigator so that when I normally navigate to it again, it shows me the first screen within the navigator?

Comment: You can refer to this answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027563/7438254

Answer (score 3):

Hey if you are using **@react-navigation/native** then just import it in your component like this

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();

navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }] 
})
```

it will reset your stacks and also you can you **replace** instead of **navigate** that will replace current to new screen

```
navigation.replace('LoginScreen')
```

I'm just putting Image over here for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.navigate({
    name: 'Profile',     // your screen name
    params: {
      user: 'jane',     //your params
    },
  })
);
```

For reference:- https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#navigate

Answer (score 0):

@this.arjun answer did not help. I managed to fix my problem by changing my above code to this

```
navigation.navigate(Screens.EXPLORE, {
                  screen: Screens.BRIEF,
                  initial: false,
                  params: {
                    briefId: briefInfo.campaign_id,
                    withPop: true,
                  },
                });
```

Then in the screen I was navigating to I added this code instead of just doing navigation.goBack()

I added the withPop conditional logic.

```
onPress={() => {
                        if (withPop) {
                          navigation.pop();
                        }
                        navigation.goBack();
                      }}
```

I am still missing an animation when I am going back from that screen. But I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few suggestions here on StackOverflow, however, **the only one that worked for me** was the following.

If you want to **clean the stack** and **add a specific screen**:

```
const resetNavigation = (navigation) => {
  navigation.popToTop();
  navigation.push('YourScreen');
};
```

If you just want to **clean the stack** and it will **default to your first screen**:

```
const resetNavigation = (navigation) => navigation.popToTop();
```

I hope this helps!