# React Native Navigation override onBack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I override react `navigate.goBack()`. My goal is to pass data from child to parent, which will used to update the parent.

There is a similar solution here [react-navigation-goback-and-update-parent-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223727/react-navigation-goback-and-update-parent-state), however they still call `this.props.navigation.goBack()`, I want to be able to use the back button in the title bar.

Comment: what navigation are you using? `react-navigation` or `react-native-navigation`?

Comment: "react-navigation"

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using call back function.

eg:

> Parent class:

Add a call back function in parent class, and pass the function to child class using props.

```
...
...

//Navigating button 
 _didTapOnButton() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("NextScreen", {
      callBackMethod: this._callBackMethod.bind(this)
    });
  }

//Call back method
_callBackMethod(dataFromChild) {
  //Your logic...
}

...
...
```

> Child Class:

```
...
...

//Child class back button
 _didTapOnBackButton() {
   const { params } = this.props.navigation.state; // Take parameter from navigation
   params.callBackMethod('data 1'); // Call back function with data: 'data 1'
   this.props.navigation.pop();
 }
...
...
```

Comment: How does this ensure, that when a user clicks the back button (the back arrow in the header) that the call back method runs. I only see this working for my own custom back buttom

Answer (score 0):

Using a callBack with componentWillUnmount solved my problem