# React navigation V5 on goback update parent

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am developing React native Expo App and working on React navigation version 5 using Hooks. How to update state on goBack()?

## screen one

```
const fetchData = async (props) => {
        //http request
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(props);
    }, [props]);

return(
<View>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Settings',{onGoBack, () => fetchData(props)})}>
</TouchableOpacity
</View>
)
```

## screen two

```
const submit = () => {
props.navigation.route.params.onGoBack();
props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

## Getting Warning

Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state, which can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `props.navigation.navigate` instead of `props.navigation.goBack` to pass params to a previous screen.
see this doc

[Troubleshooting](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/)

[Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wrong. You should just block the `back` and use `navigate` with some search params instead, because react navigation will pop off the stack correctly by default. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62822230/6002977).

In your submit, use navigate instead:

```
const submit = () => {
  props.navigation.navigate("your-parent-route?id=the-thing-you-want-to-send");
}
```

---

I think the only way to do this is to use a context somewhere above both routes, so they have some way to send state between each other.