# React navigation goBack() and update in previous screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have two screens. Each screen contains three child class. Yes, I am using the tab of each screen.
In my first screen let say. `Main-screen` has -> `ScreenA, ScreenB, ScreenC`. And my `DetailScreen` has -> `ScreenD, ScreenE, ScreenF`

Now from my `ScreenA` i have push to go to `ScreenD`. The code is here :

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen', {
            onNavigateBack: this.refresh.bind(this)
   })

 refresh(commentText) {
        alert('alert me')
    }
```

In my `ScreenD` i have one button to go back. And update the values in my `ScreenA`:

```
 this.props.navigation.state.params.onNavigateBack(this.state.commentText); 
 this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

But always i am getting error like :

```
Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state')
```

Any help would be great. My objective is to update my `screen A`, when i come back from `screen D`

**My mainScreen :**

```
 <ScreenA navigation={this.props.navigation}  tabLabel= "ScreenA" props = {this.props} tabView={this.tabView}/>
 <ScreenB navigation={this.props.navigation}  tabLabel= "ScreenB" props = {this.props} tabView={this.tabView}/>
<ScreenC navigation={this.props.navigation}   tabLabel= "ScreenC" props = {this.props} tabView={this.tabView} goToPage={ () => this.goToPage(2) }/>
```

**DetailScreen:**

```
 <ScreenD navigation={this.props.navigation}  tabLabel= "ScreenD" props = {this.props} tabView={this.tabView}/>
 <ScreenE navigation={this.props.navigation}  tabLabel= "ScreenE" props = {this.props} tabView={this.tabView}/>
<ScreenF navigation={this.props.navigation}   tabLabel= "ScreenF” props = {this.props} tabView={this.tabView} goToPage={ () => this.goToPage(2) }/>
```

My RootStackScreen :

```
import React from 'react';

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import ScreenA from './ScreenA';
import ScreenB from './ScreenB';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();


const RootStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
    <RootStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
        <RootStack.Screen name="ScreenA" component={ScreenA}/>
        <RootStack.Screen name="ScreenB" component={ScreenB}/>
    </RootStack.Navigator>
);


export default RootStackScreen;
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of one of your ScreenA or ScreenB ?

Comment: @Sennen Randika i am using flat list. Nothing else. Its very big thats why not posting here.  `export default class MainScreen  extends Component {}`

Comment: Hi @kumarbarian, which version of `react-navigation` do you use ? and if you only have `this.props.navigation.goBack();`, does it go back to previous screen ?

Comment: @Yasuooooooooo No i am getting this error `Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.goBack())`.` "version": "0.62.2"`

Comment: Have you put `constructor(props) { }` in the Screen components?

Comment: @ Sennen Randika Yes, in my parent and child class i have that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550032/13107433

Comment: in one of my parent class  DetailScreen. I din specify this `constructor(props) { }`. So after adding its going back. But if i add this line `this.props.navigation.state.params.onNavigateBack(this.state.commentText);` Then i am getting same error :Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params')

Comment: @Sennen Randika Any help . I am not able to figure it out

Comment: What's the stack navigator version you are using? `@react-navigation/stack`

Comment: You mean `React-Navigation-Stack` its  `"version": "2.7.0"`

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to your package.json file in your project.

2) Change the version of `@react-navigation/stack` to a version `5.x.x`.

Example:

```
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.14",
```

3) Run `npm install`.

4) In your ScreenA,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen', {
  onNavigateBack: (commentText) => this.refresh(commentText)
})

refresh(commentText) {
  alert('alert me')
}
```

5) In your ScreenD,

```
this.props.route.params.onNavigateBack(this.state.commentText); 
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

6) Run `npm start` and restart your project.

You will fix the problem.

**Please make sure that you are using `@react-navigation/stack: ^5.x.x`**

**Here is a working example...**

https://snack.expo.io/K1Kb_iTEW

Comment: Added like same. `"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",`. But getting same kind of error `Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.route.params)`

Comment: i have posted it.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with your implementation. You may have missed some important points. I've updated my answer with a working example. https://snack.expo.io/K1Kb_iTEW

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access navigation prop inside a child class. To do this you need to use `withNavigation` Higher Order Component.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
//    <YOUR COMPONENT>
export default withNavigation(YouChildComponent);
```

This provides the `navigation` prop to child components. You can read more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/with-navigation)

I hope it helps.

Comment: i can able to go back. But problem is when i try to add this line `this.props.navigation.state.params.onNavigateBack(this.state.commentText); `. Getting error like `Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params')`