# Can I pass params in goBack function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

I want to send params with goBack function in react navigation. Here is my code:

```
const onSelectClick = () => {
        props.navigation.goBack({ permissionId: value.id, permissionName: value.name })}
```

What I get is just `undefined`.

Comment: Where are you getting that value and how are you accessing it? Adding more code will help.

Comment: i think you should add params first from screenA to screenB and using that params when back to screenA

Comment: You can refer [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44223727/react-navigation-goback-and-update-parent-state) .

Comment: Thank's all got it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    navigation.dispatch(state => {
        const prevRoute = state.routes[state.routes.length - 2];
        return CommonActions.navigate({
            name: prevRoute.name,
            params: {
                
            },
            merge: true,
         });
     });
```

This is for 6.x react navigation, probably will work in 7.x as well.
This emulates goBack(params);

No need to pass `previousScreen` as parameter.