# goback with prams in react native. goback() to main screena nd display snackbar

Tags: react-native

I have Settings screen where user have many options along with Send Feedback button. If user click on Send Feedback button user will redirect to feedback screen where user will enter details and submit the form. On submit user will redirect to Settings screen again I have used goback for this. But now i want to display snackbar with message Thank for your feedback. this will be on Settings screen only. How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44227835?

Comment: You can use navigate as you use to navigate to the current screen: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen

Comment: I want to chow snackbar on settings screen and not on Feedback screen.